# Wrap a 2-D array as a tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I have a, for example, numpy array `X` with a shape of [500, 20]. I want to convert it to a tuple `Y` that has 1 element, which is that numpy array `X`. If I call `len(Y)`, it should return 1. If I call
`type(Y)`, it should return `tuple`. If I call `Y[0].shape,` it should return [500, 20]. If I call
`type(Y[0])`, it should return `np.array`. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: what about `Y = (X,)`

Comment: @ScienceSnake It doesn't work. It will return a tuple with 500 elements. It will just flatten.

Comment: @Epsi95 that should work! Thanks!